# Subgroup of general linear group over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ generated by two matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have two matrices: $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 &1\\1 & 2&1\\1 &2&0\end{bmatrix}$
and $B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 &0\\0 & 1&0\\0 &1&2\end{bmatrix}$. I need to describe subgroup generated by these matrices.I know that group generated by A and B, say G, is isomorphic to $Q_{8}$ or $D_{4}$ or $S_{3}$ or $S_{4}$ or $A_{4}$. Any hints?

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: @JeanMarie i found that $A^4 = 1$ and $B^2 = 1$

Comment: @JeanMarie i dont understand. I tried to show that G isomorphic to $D_{4}$ but $BAB = A^{-1}$ fails ( $D_{4} = <x,y|x^4 = y^2 = 1, yxy = x^{-1}>$ if i'm right)

Comment: Are you sure $BAB\neq A^3$? I get that it does on Mathematica.

Comment: @AlecB-G oops. Thank you!

Comment: It looks a group of order 8. Thus the choice would remain between $Q_8$ or $D_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $A^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&2\\ 0&2&0\\ 2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$,  $A^4=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $B^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $BAB=A^{-1}$ since $A^3=A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\ 2&1&2\\\ 0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $BAB=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\ 2&1&2\\\ 0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$.

The dihedral group $D_8$ has presentation $\langle a,b\ |\ a^4=b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}\rangle$, clearly $A$ and $B$ satisfy these relations, so we can conclude $\langle A,B\rangle\cong D_8$.